# Learn Python the Hard way, exercise 25, not getting expected result

Tags: python

I'm doing exercise 25 of Learn Python the Hard Way and I'm not getting the expected result.  When I call print_first_word on the parameter words (which is an list), I type into the shell:

> ex25.print_first_word(words)

I am told I should see:

> All

Instead, I see

> wait.

It's worth mentioning that words was:

> ['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']

Here is my code:

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This Function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence"""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

Comment: I ran the program and see "All" so I think your program is correct

Comment: My guess: Your program is in some text file and you are testing it from the interactive shell and you made some changes to the file. Try `reload(ex25)`.

Comment: @FredLarson his `print_first_word` is specifying the index 0

Comment: As a side note, your Python code would be a lot clearer if you would stop hiding built-in functions in custom wrappers. For instance, why define `def sort_words(words): return sorted(words)`? That's not even as useful as `sort_words = sorted`!

Comment: @Ashish: Yeah, I saw that and deleted my comment.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Because he is a beginner(I guess) and he will be doing these things to understand clearly..

Comment: See here: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html

Comment: @Nabin I work with first-year university students learning new languages all the time: we teach them the _right_ way to do things, not how to make their code longer and more difficult to read!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist But then again, this tutorial is called "Learn Python the _hard_ way", not "Learn Python the _right_ way". ;-)

Comment: I have to agree with @tobias_k on this one: Zed Shaw dismisses partly the right way in favor of the hard way here. The method here is repetitive reinforcement, rather than corrective instruction.

Comment: For what it's worth, I get flak from both camps when I include more complicated OOP solutions to beginners on SO trying to do things that should be done with objects before they're ready to look at objects. I'm with @Two-BitAlchemist that you teach a student the RIGHT way of doing things, and if they CAN'T do it the right way, you find another exercise.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're doing this in IDLE (or another interactive shell) and your previous "test runs" have affected your input. Try `print`ing `words` first, and see if it is what you expect it to be. Your code looks right.

Remember that `list.pop` (as you have in your function `print_first_word(words)` actually REMOVES its target from the list. That is to say:

```
words = ['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']
words.pop(0) # returns 'All', but since I don't assign it anywhere, who cares
print(words)
# ['good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']
```

If you're NOT TRYING to remove an element from a list, don't `pop` it, just slice it.

```
words = ['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']
words[0] # ALSO returns 'All', though again I'm not doing anything with it
print(words)
# ['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you should keep in mind. First, the `pop()` method modifies the list it's used on; once you access an item using `pop()`, it's no longer in the list. Look at this sequence of commands:

```
>>> words = ['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']
>>> words.pop(0)
'All'
>>> words.pop(0)
'good'
>>> words.pop(0)
'things'
>>> words.pop(0)
'come'
>>> words.pop(0)
'to'
>>> words.pop(0)
'those'
>>> words.pop(0)
'who'
>>> words.pop(0)
'wait.'

>>> words.pop(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    words.pop(0)
IndexError: pop from empty list
>>>
```

Second, and this is pretty confusing, lists are passed by reference. What this means is is that when you call `print_first_word(words)`, `words.pop(0)` doesn't just modify a local variable within your function. It modifies your original list! So, if you call `print_first_word(words)` multiple times, its output will differ each time, similar to what you see above.

You can fix this by using `word = words[0]`, which merely retrieves the value at 0, instead of `word = words.pop(0)`.

Comment: "pretty confusing, lists are passed by reference" Maybe it's a lack of experience with languages that copy objects to methods, but this seems pretty straight-forwards to me. If I give a method my object and ask it to mutate it, I would be shocked if that method mutated a copy of it instead!

Comment: @AdamSmith: Most Python constructs (ints, floats, strings, etc.) are passed by value, so the fact that lists aren't can confuse the Python beginner. I remember this giving me grief early on!

Comment: @Matthew: in the sense you're using "passed by reference" and "passed by value", ints, floats, and strings are passed by reference too.  It's simply that they're immutable, so you don't notice.  Try `def f(x): print(id(x))` and then `a = 10; print(id(a)); f(a)`.

Comment: @AdamSmith: That's not what my book said, but you're right. Good to know!

Comment: @DSM courtesy tag, I think Matthew's last comment was to you :)

Answer (score 1):

As I said I did not change is single character in your code and it is running perfectly fine. Here is what I have

```
    def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

    words=['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']

    print_first_word(words)
```

And the result is `All`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not importing the file I thought I was.  Someone who commented on my question at [Learn Python The Hard Way, Exercise 25, module has no attribute 'print_last_word'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842768/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-25-module-has-no-attribute-print-last-word) suggested I

```
print ex25.__file__
```

This showed me the file I was actually importing from. Then, I made sure to import from the correct path.

Please let me know if this is better posted as an update/edit to my question.  Thanks!