# Learn Python The Hard Way, Exercise 25, module has no attribute 'print_last_word'

Tags: python

Here is the exercise I am working on: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html

I am getting the following error message: "AttributeError: module object has no attribute 'print_last_word' even though I have defined it in my code(see below).  I imported the relevant file using

> import ex25

I'm calling it using

> ex25.print_last_word(words)

All other functions are recognized.

However, dir(ex25) confirms what the error message says.  I have saved the file and checked the spelling (though another set of eyes might help).  Any help is appreciated.

```
def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping if off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word
```

Comment: How did you import the module?

Comment: Can you show the code that's calling `print_last_word`?

Comment: There are a number of things which can cause this.  First, let's try to rule out some easy stuff.  Try `import ex25` and then `print ex25.__file__`; you may not be importing the code you think you are.  If that looks okay, try `for line in open(ex25.__file__.rstrip("c")): print line` and see whether or not `print_last_word` is actually there.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so we can get this question off the unanswered list.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from DSM fixed it Specifically, it was

> `print ex25.__file__`; you may not be importing the code you think you
>   are.

This showed me the filepath it was printing, which was not what I wanted.  This also helped answer the question I posted at [Learn Python the Hard way, exercise 25, not getting expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841719/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-25-not-getting-expected-result)

THANK YOU DSM